# When do I use cp --attributes-only

Tags: files, cp

Doing some study on basic Unix commands and trying to get an example when I want to use the following command line option `--attributes-only` for command `cp`

here is from `cp` man page

```
--attributes-only
              don't copy the file data, just the attributes
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Say you have a file, `file1`, that you know should have identical attributes to `file2` (you know that `file2` has the correct attributes).

```
$ stat file{1,2}
  File: 'file1'
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: 1fh/31d Inode: 2326956     Links: 1
Access: (0600/-rw-------)  Uid: ( 1000/   chris)   Gid: ( 1000/   chris)
Access: 2013-12-24 09:53:20.248720441 +0800
Modify: 2013-12-24 09:53:20.248720441 +0800
Change: 2013-12-24 09:53:31.011984772 +0800
 Birth: -
  File: 'file2'
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: 1fh/31d Inode: 2326957     Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1000/   chris)   Gid: ( 1000/   chris)
Access: 2013-12-24 09:53:21.045382001 +0800
Modify: 2013-12-24 09:53:21.045382001 +0800
Change: 2013-12-24 09:53:21.045382001 +0800
 Birth: -
```

One way to make sure that they match is to go and check `file2` and manually apply the attributes:

```
$ chmod 644 file1
```

This is, however, cumbersome to automate and script. It would be easier to get the attributes from `file2` and apply them to `file1` programatically.

```
$ cp --attributes-only --preserve file2 file1
$ stat file1
  File: 'file1'
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: 1fh/31d Inode: 2326956     Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1000/   chris)   Gid: ( 1000/   chris)
Access: 2013-12-24 09:53:21.045382001 +0800
Modify: 2013-12-24 09:53:21.045382001 +0800
Change: 2013-12-24 09:57:06.320604649 +0800
 Birth: -
```

`--attributes-only` doesn't do anything by itself; it needs to be combined with other attribute preservation flags. From `info cp`:

```
--attributes-only
     Copy only the specified attributes of the source file to the
     destination.  If the destination already exists, do not alter its
     contents.  See the `--preserve' option for controlling which
     attributes to copy.
```

`--preserve` is used above, which is documented as being equivalent to `--preserve=mode,ownership,timestamps`. Internally, you can think of this as "don't copy data" rather than "copy attributes only", which is why you have to pass `--preserve` regardless.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a smartphone, you can choose music from PC, when you're far from it:

```
$ cp -rn --attributes-only ~/Music smartphone/Music
```

When you far from the PC, delete directories, you want copy in future.

```
$ cp -rn ~/Music smartphone/Music
```

You get choosen music and empty files.